# Does data.table have a way to not stop on bad lines in fread?

Tags: r, data.table

Does data.table have a way to not error out on bad lines and just drop them and continue while reading the data ?
Something like pandas read_csv which has error_bad_lines and warn_bad_lines
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Comment: I also wish `fread` has this kind of option. Last time when I tried to read a large `csv` file, `fread` stopped at position 19%, I fixed that line, and it stopped at another position which is quite close to the previous one. I thought there would be many such kind of bad lines, so I ended up by clean the data first using two line of `perl`. If there are only a few bad lines, `error_bad_lines` option helps; if there are too many, the data becomes incomplete. So we'd better clean it first.